# Video Files in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, gridfs

I am creating a website in which I will primarily store bunch of videos and pdf's and I am using MongoDB as my database but my problem is if I save my videos directly to the MongoDB does it affect the speed of my website whenever the user will try to fetch and play the video file? Any help will be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are serious about streaming videos to users you should consider using a CDN. In this case videos stored in MongoDB using GridFS should be fine. If you don't want to use a CDN then you will get better performance serving the videos from S3 and keep the URL in MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

You could in principle make video storage work with GridFS, but due to chunking I imagine this will be quite awkward.

There is probably a better solution available. Even something like storage in s3 seems like a superior alternative to me. You get much easier streaming capability and much lower storage costs.

Comment: Yeah that's what I imagined it's quite awkward  to use GridFs and I think there will be performance issue.